# Homebrew gives a warning: "You have MacPorts or Fink installed"

Tags: macos, homebrew, macports, mac-pro, fink

I just got a new Mac Pro with OS X 10.9. When I run:

```
brew doctor
```

I get the warning:

```
Warning: You have MacPorts or Fink installed:
/opt/local/bin/port

This can cause trouble. You don't have to uninstall them, but you may want to 
temporarily move them out of the way, e.g.
sudo mv /opt/local ~/macports
```

I didn't install MacPorts or Fink, why do I get the warning?

Comment: The file `/opt/local/bin/port` is the MacPorts executable, thus it is installed.
What happens if you try the commands `port version` and `port list installed`? I use both Homebrew and MacPorts and I get the warning but everything works fine for me :)

Comment: i tried, but there's no port. "zsh: command not found: port"

Comment: Try /opt/local/bin/port version  etc - /opt/local/bin is not on yours or the default path

Answer (score 6):

Note that some 3rd-party packaging tools may sometimes automatically install MacPorts. I recall RVM does that (or at least used to, I don't know the current state), so while you're not aware of actually installing it manually, it might still be there.

If you move `/opt/local` to a different location that might break whatever pulled in MacPorts in the first place.

Comment: This is not an answer and should be a comment

Comment: It is one possible explanation for the question "I didn't install MacPorts or Fink, why do I get the warning?" asked in the original post. Since I do not see any other questions in the original post, I'd argue that this in fact *is* an answer. Of course, if you disagree and have the appropriate means to do so, feel free to make this a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The error reports that `/opt/local/bin/port` exists.

- If you haven't installed it, the error is shown because the path exists. Move the executable:

  ```
  sudo mv /opt/local/bin/port ~/Desktop
  ```
- If you have installed it, you can run the command given:

  ```
  sudo mv /opt/local ~/macports
  ```

Comment: i didn't installed, and "port" doesn't exist. And there's no path "/opt/local/bin/port", it's wired.

Comment: Meanwhile there's a 'bin" under '/opt/local', and there are many files like 'perl, openssl' etc. If i move it to '~/macports', won't it effect these executive files? Not very clear about this.

Comment: How dod the files get in /opt/local/bin? Yi had to have installed something that did this